# C# Get a drive's Name via it's Serial ID

Tags: wmi, hard-drive

I am using C# and working on Visual Studio 2015.
I need to get a Connected USB drive's name from it's Serial ID.
I tried using WMI Class the query: "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk"

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
            ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk");

        foreach (ManagementObject item in searcher.Get())
        {
            if (item != null && item["VolumeSerialNumber"] != null && item["VolumeName"] != null)
            {
                if (item["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString() == "50D76BF4")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{item["VolumeName"]} Is Connected and It's Letter is {item["Name"]}");
                }
            }          
        }
```

However, There VolumeSerialNumber is not ther real Serial ID. It is changed when the disk is formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

I wrote a method that reutrns a hard drive's name and letter from it's **real and unchangable** id.

You need to refernce System.Management

this is the code:

```
 public static string GetDriveLetterAndLabelFromID(string id)
    {
         ManagementClass devs = new ManagementClass(@"Win32_Diskdrive");
        {
            ManagementObjectCollection moc = devs.GetInstances();
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                string a = (string)mo["SerialNumber"];
                if (a== id)
                {
                    foreach (ManagementObject b in
                    mo.GetRelated("Win32_DiskPartition"))
                    {
                        foreach (ManagementBaseObject c in b.GetRelated("Win32_LogicalDisk"))
                    {
                        string result = $"HardDrive Name: {c["VolumeName"].ToString()}\nHardDrive Letter: {c["DeviceID"]}";                           
                        return result;
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```